# Accessing NOAA Data via BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to access the NOAA Data via BigQuery. I used the following code to achieve the same :

```
import os
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("my-json-file-path-with-filename.json")

from google.cloud import bigquery
# Create a "Client" object
client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials)
```

But getting the following error :

```
DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
```

Can somebody please help. I have already created my service account but still facing this issue.

Comment: It should work, double check your json key file path (must be full path). Also, you could add a [scope](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#scope-response) ([list of scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes)) like [in this example](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#service-account-private-key-files).

Or set the environment variable [GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries#before-you-begin) externally or internally as suggested by user6016731.

Answer (score 0):

import os
from google.cloud.bigquery.client import Client

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'path_to_json_file'
bq_client = Client()