# DefaultCredentialsError raised saying 'File not found'

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text, google-speech-to-text-api

I am a beginner trying to perform some Speech-to-Text as an experiment. I am new to Google Cloud API, and I am getting stuck at the Credential Authentication.

I have used [this](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize) code to try to transcribe a 20 min long audio file to text. I am using Google Colaboratory for this.

My code is simply the imports, a code block for adding the JSON file to the env path, the function in the link, and a code block executing the function with the file path to the .wav file. I haven't edited the code, just copied it and used the same type of audio file they use (.wav).

I have followed the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#windows) to get the JSON file for authorization.

To set an environment variable for `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` I inserted a code block before the function like so:

```
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]='folder_path\\My First Project-##########.json'
```

This raised no errors so I assume that the credentials are added to the path. However, when I execute the function like so:

```
sample_long_running_recognize('folder_path\\audio_file.wav')
```

I get the error:

```
DefaultCredentialsError: File folder_path\\My First Project-##########.json was not found.
```

From the same 'Getting started with Authentication' link I have shared above, there is a function `implicit()` given to test whether the authentication is done correctly. I defined the function and ran it, and I got the same error. What exactly am I doing wrong? I also ran `set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=folder_path\\My First Project-##########.json` in cmd as the instructions say. It didn't return any error there either. So why does it say the file is not found?

I have re-checked multiple times, there isn't an issue with the filepath, I have simply copied it and added double backslashes (this was due to the error `SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape`)

Comment: Where are you running this code? What platform/OS is it? If you run `python -c "open('folder_path\\My First Project-##########.json')"`, what happens?

Comment: Do you have GCloud installed on your environment?

Comment: Have you set the client()? Eg: `os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'folder_path\\My First Project-##########.json' = Client()` ref.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61364931/accessing-noaa-data-via-bigquery

Comment: Or `client = speech_client.SpeechClient(credential=...)` Ref: https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/0.32.0/speech/gapic/api.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved that problem setting the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` directly in the project folder and removing the quotes of the `PATH`, just run this on your prompt

```
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=C:\Users\yourUser\credentials-file.json
```

without any quotes

Comment: I was able to get it to work keeping GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in a different folder but just removing the quotes.